# RXSwift Flat Map

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Im new to RXSwift and in my app I use Google Places Service to get a Place coordinates and then I have to hit my API with get request to check if the fetched coordinate is within our operation areas how can I flat map the both requests ?

Here is My Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    progress.startAnimating()
    GMSPlacesClient.shared().lookUpPlaceID(placesArray[indexPath.row].placeID) { (place, error) in
        //check if place is within the bounds array
        if error == nil {
            if checkPlace(place: place!){
                // valid location
            }else{
                // un valid location
            }
            self.progress.stopAnimating()
        }
        
        print(place?.coordinate.latitude)
    }
}

}


func checkPlace(place : GMSPlace)->Bool{
    
    // Hit the api with get request
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this using my [CLE library](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools):

```
import Cause_Logic_Effect
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import UIKit

extension ExampleViewController {
    func connect() {
        let api = API(session: URLSession.shared, activityIndicator: ActivityIndicator(), errorRouter: ErrorRouter())

        let gmsPlace = tableView.rx.modelSelected(Place.self)
            .map(\.placeID)
            .flatMapLatest { GMSPlacesClient.shared().rx.lookUpPlaceID($0) }
            .share()

        let isValidPlace = gmsPlace
            .flatMapLatest { api.load(.checkPlace(place: $0)) }
            .share()

        Observable.zip(gmsPlace, isValidPlace)
            .compactMap { $0.1 ? $0.0 : nil }
            .bind(onNext: { place in
                // the place is valid, do something with it.
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        // let the user know that the place is not valid.
        Observable.zip(gmsPlace, isValidPlace)
            .compactMap { $0.1 ? nil : "\($0.0.name) is not a valid place." }
            .bind(onNext: presentScene(animated: true) { message in
                UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    .scene { $0.connectOK() }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        api.isActive
            .bind(to: activityIndicatorView.rx.isAnimating)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        api.error.map(\.localizedDescription)
            .bind(onNext: presentScene(animated: true) { message in
                UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    .scene { $0.connectOK() }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

extension Endpoint where T == Bool {
    static func checkPlace(place: GMSPlace) -> Endpoint {
        fatalError() // Create the URLRequest and function for processing the response here
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: GMSPlacesClient {
    func lookUpPlaceID(_ id: String) -> Observable<GMSPlace> {
        Observable.create { [base] observer in
            base.lookUpPlaceID(id) { place, error in
                if let place = place {
                    observer.onSuccess(place)
                }
                else {
                    observer.onError(error ?? RxError.unknown)
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```